# Loop in array through objects with find()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the `state.1.extras.mileage`, I have an array with 3 objects with the values:  1000, 2000, 3000. I want to make a function that when an user inputs a number between 1 & 1000 you get the object

```
        {
          name: '1.000 mileage',
          mileage: '1.000',
          description: 'mileage-description',
        },
```

when the input is between 1000 & 2000 you will get the second object,
and when you input is between 2000&3000 you get the third object.

This is my current function:

```
export const getMileageName = (
  state: GlobalState,
  pdbId: ?string = null,
  index?: number = 0,
): string => {
  const mileages = getMileages(state, pdbId);
  if (!mileages || !mileages[index]) {
    throw Error('Couldn\'t find mileage');
  }

  return mileages[index].name;
};

export const getMileageByKilometers = (
  state: GlobalState,
  pdbId: ?string = null,
  kilometers: number,
) => {
  const mileages = getMileages(state, pdbId);
  console.log(mileages);
  return mileages.find([0]);
};




const state = {
  pdb: {
    items: {
      1: {
        extras: {
          duration: [
            {
              name: 'duration-name',
              description: 'duration',
              duration: '40',
            },
          ],
          extra: [
            { name: 'extra' },
          ],
          contract: [
            { name: 'contract' },
          ],
          claimfree: [
            { name: 'claimfree' },
          ],
          mileage: [
            {
              name: '1.000 mileage',
              mileage: '1.000',
              description: 'mileage-description',
            },
            {
              name: '2.000 mileage',
              mileage: '2.000',
              description: 'mileage-description 2',
            },
            {
              name: '3.000 mileage',
              mileage: '3.000',
              description: 'mileage-description 3',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: In your case, given the current expected input and range of mileages, I think it would actually be easier and more efficient to just convert it into an index. Here's a performance benchmark demonstrating the difference between this and Rodius' answer https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/11099

Answer (score 1):

You have an array with three objects, each one with a mileage value. Using the javascript `find` function you will get the 1st value that meets the condition you state.

Your function:

```
getObject(speed) {
  const mileage= [
            {
              name: '1000 mileage',
              mileage: '1000',
              description: 'mileage-description',
            },
            {
              name: '2000 mileage',
              mileage: '2000',
              description: 'mileage-description 2',
            },
            {
              name: '3000 mileage',
              mileage: '3000',
              description: 'mileage-description 3',
            }
          ];

  return mileage.find(obj => parseInt(obj.mileage, 10) >= speed);
}
```

Snippet below:

```js
var speed = [800, 1000, 1001, 995, 2000, 2958, 3000];
console.log(speed);
var getMileage = (speed) => {
  const mileage= [
      {
        name: '1000 mileage',
        mileage: '1000',
        description: 'mileage-description',
      },
      {
        name: '2000 mileage',
        mileage: '2000',
        description: 'mileage-description 2',
      },
      {
        name: '3000 mileage',
        mileage: '3000',
        description: 'mileage-description 3',
      }
    ];
    
    return mileage.find(obj => parseInt(obj.mileage, 10) >= speed);
};

console.log(speed.forEach(s => console.log(s, 'object: ', getMileage(s))));
```